# Различие между .addEventListener и .onresize

Tags: javascript

В чем различия `.addEventListener("resize",function(){})` и `.onresize = function(){}`?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addEventListener` позволяет добавлять несколько обработчиков на одно действие. Удобно, если вы используете сторонние библиотеки и не можете быть уверены, что более никто кроме вас не установил свой обработчик.

Comment: А как называются методы вроде .onresize (ну есть EventListeners, а это что?).

Comment: Сам onresize и подобные ему называются событиями (event). Функции, который вы помещаете в них - обработчики событий.